# Connecting to a test websocket server works, but connecting to my Node.js server fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm using the code below to test websockets on my browser:

```
this.webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org");

this.webSocket.onopen = function(evt) {
  cc.log("Send Text WS was opened.");             
};

this.webSocket.onmessage = function(evt) {
  this.socketSendTextTimes++;
  var textStr = "response text msg: " + evt.data + this.socketSendTextTimes;
  cc.log(textStr);
};
```

The code works well, but if I connect to my own server running the code below:

```
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) { 
  // Send HTML headers and message
  res.writeHead(200,{ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }); 
  res.end('<h1>Hello!</h1>');
});

var socket = io.listen(server);

socket.set('destroy upgrade', false);
socket.on('connection', function(client) {   
  client.on('message', function(event) { 
    console.log('Received message from client!', event);
  });

  client.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('Server has disconnected');
  });
});

server.listen(8080);
console.log('start to listen');
```

My browser displays:

```
hello!
```

But the listening socket does not do anything. How can I connect to the Socket.IO server using websockets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socket.IO uses alternate transport methods than the native websocket, even when emulating websockets themselves. You will need the client library to connect to Socket.IO sockets.